# Issue Running Browserify to Front End

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, path, browserify

I've been looking online for a while with no success. I am not knowledgeable with Browserify or even NodeJS so bare that in mind. Around the center of [Browserify](https://browserify.org/) website, it states that all I need to do is create the function, pack the file with browserify file.js -o output.js, and include as script for the front end.

**Files I'm translating with browserify** (I made the functions in the global space, browserify does not do this from what I've read)

read:

```
const stateLogic = require('./stateLogic.js');

var x = document.getElementById(exhibit).value

window.read = function()
{
    const logic = new stateLogic();
    logic.read(x);
    alert("executed");
};
```

write:

```
const stateLogic = require('./stateLogic.js');

    var x = document.getElementById("exhibit").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("path").value;

window.write = function()
{
    const logic = new stateLogic();
    logic.append(x, y);
    alert("executed");
};
```

**html file** (assume all paths are correct)

```
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <p class="sign" style="font-family: 'scifi';" align="center">D ° R 3 C T O R ° 3 S</p>
    <form class="form1">
      <input id = "exhibit" class="un " type="text" align="center" placeholder="Exhibit">
      <input id = "path" class="pass" type="text" align="center" placeholder="Directory">
      <button type="button" onclick="write()">click</button>
      <!--<a class="submit" align="center" onclick="write()">Get Data</a>-->
      <p class="forgot" align="center"><a href="#">Aid</p>
      </form>
            
                
    </div>
     
    <script src="js/append1.js"> </script>

    <script src="js/control.js"></script>

    <script src="js/read1.js"> </script>
</body>
```

**Errors**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    at assertPath (append1.js:4626)
    at Object.dirname (append1.js:4891)
    at Function.load.path (append1.js:12502)
    at load (append1.js:12480)
    at Object.<anonymous> (append1.js:11785)
    at Object.<anonymous> (append1.js:11787)
    at Object.77.node-gyp-build (append1.js:11787)
    at o (append1.js:1)
    at append1.js:1
    at Object.<anonymous> (append1.js:11880)
read1.js:4626 Uncaught TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    at assertPath (read1.js:4626)
    at Object.dirname (read1.js:4891)
    at Function.load.path (read1.js:12502)
    at load (read1.js:12480)
    at Object.<anonymous> (read1.js:11785)
    at Object.<anonymous> (read1.js:11787)
    at Object.77.node-gyp-build (read1.js:11787)
    at o (read1.js:1)
    at read1.js:1
    at Object.<anonymous> (read1.js:11880)
```

**Extra info**

- Browsers: Brave, Firefox, Chrome
- Tried without window space (it seems to need it)

**Inquiries**

What am I doing wrong? And can you explain why my approach is wrong? Thank you for your time :).

Answer (score 1):

without testing, because i dont understand what you like to do...

read: you wrote:

```
var x = document.getElementById(exhibit).value
```

The id should be written in ''.

```
var x = document.getElementById('exhibit').value
```

Maybe there's the problem

BR Patrick

Comment: Hello, good eye but still getting the same errors.